# How do I define and set a a pointer to a 2d array that's passed twice in the middle class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array in my MainProcessor

```
float waveforms[2][1080] = { {0}, {0} };
```

And I pass it to a SynthVoice like this:

```
osc1Voice->setWavetable(waveforms, 0); //[1]
osc2Voice->setWavetable(waveforms, 1);
```

There I read it like this in SynthVoice.h:

```
typedef float array_of_wavetable[1080];
void setWavetable(array_of_wavetable* waveform, int number)
    {
      wavetable = waveform;
      id = number;

}
```

so i can use it like this in my SynthVoice class:

```
wavetable[id][first_sample + int(phase_0)]
```

Now I have moved [1] in a new class (OscilatorProcessor.h) and I want to set a pointer from MainProcessor -> OscillatorProcessor -> SynthVoice in a way that I can use it as wavetable[id][phase].

Now I don't know how to pass it from my MainProcessor to my OscillatorProcessor in the middle. So I can read it in the same way in the SynthVoice class.

I hope this made  sense. Thank you for your time

edit:  minimal reproducible example

```
#include <iostream>

typedef float array_of_wavetable[1080];

class SynthVoice
{
public:
  void setWavetable(array_of_wavetable* waveform, int number)
  {
    wavetable = waveform;
    id = number;
  }

  void outputWavetable()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1080; i++)
    {
      std::cout << wavetable[id][i];
    }
  }

private:
  array_of_wavetable * wavetable;
  int id;
};

class OscillatorProcessor
{
public:

  void setWavetable(array_of_wavetable * waveform, int number)
  {
    wavetable = waveform;
    id = number;
  }

  void sendWaveToVoice()
  {
    SynthVoice voice;
    voice.setWavetable(wavetable, id);
    voice.outputWavetable();
  }

private:
  array_of_wavetable * wavetable;
  int id;
};

int main() {
  float waveform_templates[4][1080] = { {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} };

  OscillatorProcessor oscillator;
  oscillator.setWavetable(waveform_templates, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a case where using `std::array<float, 1080>` would make everything much much simpler.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the problem that you've run into.  Can you provided a [mcve] of your current situation?  Because from the code you provided and what you said you are trying to do worked for me, so I don't know why doing the same didn't work for you.  (I did not use `std::array<float, 1080>`, but that would make it easier.)

Comment: I added a minimum reproducible example, it outputs nothing. If you could take a look at it it would be much appreciated

Comment: What could it output? `setWaveTable()` sets member variables and returns. Then the program exits.